# Adding each multiple of x to an answer variable in C#

Tags: c#

I am writing an application where each multiple of 4 and 6 is added to a total variable named answer.

I am receiving this error, "The name 'sum' does not exist in the current context" 
 It is occurring at Console.WriteLine(sum);.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args, int answer)
        {
            //Local Variables
            int i;
            int total = 0;

            //Initialize Console
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number to begin");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            //Create integer from string input
            int number = int.Parse(input);

            //For Loop Looking for Multiples
            for (i = 0; i < number; i++)
            {
                if (i % 4 == 0 || i % 6 == 0)
                {
                    int sum;
                    sum = total + i;
                }
                Console.WriteLine(sum);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Move `int sum;` out of the loop

Comment: You are defining `sum` inside of the `if` statement, then trying to access it after the statement closes. This is invalid because `sum` does not exist outside of the scope of the `if` statement. Here is a good article on [variable scopes](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c-sharp/).

Answer (score 1):

Each *local variable* exists within its *scope* `{...}` where it's *declared*:

```
            if (i % 4 == 0 || i % 6 == 0)
            {                          // <- Scope of sum begins here
                int sum;
                sum = total + i;
            }                          // <- Scope of sum ends here

            Console.WriteLine(sum);    // <- sum doesn't exists here (out of scope)
```

Let's move `sum` *declaration* out of the `if` and loop (in order to declare `sum` in a wider scope):

```
    //DONE: , int answer dropped 
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {  // <- now sum scope begins here
        ...
        int sum = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            if (i % 4 == 0 || i % 6 == 0)
            {
                //DONE: you probably want to add i to sum, not to total
                sum = sum + i;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sum);
        }

    }  // <- sum scope ends here
```

Answer (score 1):

You Have To Declare The Variable sum out of if statement because this variable known only in if statement when the code get out of if statement the program doesn't know sum...The program know sum only in if statement

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you face such error because `sum` is declared inside `if` scope and it is not visible outside. You should move `sum` variable declaration out of `if` scope to make it visible for `Console.WriteLine(...)` method.

But as you mentioned, you just need to store a total number. So you don't even need `sum` variable here because you have `total` variable.

So let's rewrite this code like that:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args, int answer)
    {
        //Local Variables
        int i;
        int total = 0;

        //Initialize Console
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number to begin");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        //Create integer from string input
        int number = int.Parse(input);

        //For Loop Looking for Multiples
        for (i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            if (i % 4 == 0 || i % 6 == 0)
            {                    
                total += i;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(total);
        }
    }
}
```